Multiple regression and pseudoreplication
I have an experiment where fluke infection is estimated non destructively by 2 different assays at 3 separate time points. After a set number of weeks the animals are culled, the liver extracted and the definitive, terminal assay, fluke number in the liver, is determined. I'd like to assess the effect of the two different assays and time of assessment on estimation of fluke numbers in the liver. I'd like some advice on the best way to do this. I've used multiple regression but to do this and it works but for my software, NCSS, I had to replicate the fluke numbers to match the 3 time points as there is only one terminal fluke assay per individual and assays at each of the 3 time points for the non-destructive assays. It feels OK but at the back of my mind is the issue of pseudoreplication. Any advice?

I see a couple issues here. First, if the number of tumors is not very large, then you should probably be using some kind of count regression. Second, you need to deal with the repeated measures; two common ways of doing this are multilevel models and generalized estimating equations. Replication doesn't sou d like a good method here.

The description of the data & analysis is not completely clear. Do you repeat the terminal assay number because you intend it's the outcome variable (Y) while the 3 non-destructive assay numbers are treated as predictors? This doesn't seem right because the infection might have progressed between the different time points. Anyway, it would be really helpful if you can share the data. Alternatively, a simulated dataset with the same structure as the real one but with fake -- though realistic -- measurement values.
